# Removing part of a filename for multiple files on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to remove **test.extra** from all of my file names in current directory

```
for filename in *.fasta;do 

    echo $filename | sed \e 's/test.extra//g'

done
```

but it complains about not founding file.echo is to be sure it list correctly.

Comment: For one thing, you have a `\e` instead of `-e`.

Comment: Please provide some examples of the full filenames you're processing.

Comment: Do you want to remove 'test.extra' globally I mean replace all matches, and not just the first ?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

First of all use 'sed -e' instead of '\e'

And I would suggest you do it this way in bash

```
for filename in *.fasta; do 
    [ -f "$filename" ] || continue
    mv "$filename" "${filename//test.extra/}"

done
```

Comment: My filenames has spaces. Modifying the above and using the below line worked for me `mv "$filename" "${filename//test.extra/}"`

Comment: What is that 2nd parameter to `mv` (the `"${filename//test.extra/}"`)? Looks like a regex, except the match and replacement are switched. Tried looking it up, but don't know how to find that through Google.

Comment: @GG2 google for "string operations in bash", it is a string replacement syntax

Answer (score 59):

Try `rename "extra.test" "" *`

Or `rename 's/extra.test//;' *`

```
$ find
./extra.test-eggs.txt
./extra.testbar
./fooextra.test
./ham-extra.test-blah

$ rename "extra.test" "" *
$ find
./-eggs.txt
./bar
./foo
./ham--blah
```

Comment: I you get the error `Bareword "extra.test" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (eval 2) line 1.`, try using this syntax instead: `rename 's/extra.test//;' *`

Answer (score 40):

I know this thread is old, but the following oneliner, inspired from the validated answer, helped me a lot ;)

```
for filename in ./*; do mv "./$filename" "./$(echo "$filename" | sed -e 's/test.extra//g')";  done
```

Comment: Yes, it is correct, but think for a minute what is there is a directory (not a file) over there.

Answer (score 30):

Try the `rename` command:

```
rename 's/test.extra//g' *.fasta
```

Comment: What `rename` command is that? I can't find one which supports sed-like replacement syntax.

Comment: This rename version is actually a part of perl package.

Comment: just install and use `perl-rename` - it follows this exact syntax and is very handy with regexps

Comment: On fedora, I used rename like `rename 'test.extra' '' *.fasta`, with the arguments being the substring, what to replace it with, and which files to rename

Answer (score 4):

```
$ mmv '*test.extra*.fasta' '#1#2.fasta'
```

This is safe in the sense that `mmv` will not do anything at all if it would otherwise overwrite existing files (there are command-line options to turn this off).

Answer (score 3):

```
 // EXTENSION - File extension of files
 // STRING - String to be Replace

      for filename in *.EXTENSION;
      do  [ -f "$filename" ] || continue;  
      mv "$filename" "${filename//STRING/}"; 
      done
```

Answer (score 2):

In **Kali linux** rename command is *rename.ul*

```bash
rename.ul 'string-to-remove' 'string-to-replace-with' *.jpg
```

example: rename.ul 'useless-string' '' *.jpg
This will delete useless-string from all the jpg image's filname.