# bash removing part of a file name

Tags: bash, shell, sed, rename, mv

I have the following files in the following format:

```
$ ls CombinedReports_LLL-*'('*.csv
CombinedReports_LLL-20140211144020(Untitled_1).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-20140211144020(Untitled_11).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-20140211144020(Untitled_110).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-20140211144020(Untitled_111).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-20140211144020(Untitled_12).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-20140211144020(Untitled_13).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-20140211144020(Untitled_14).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-20140211144020(Untitled_15).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-20140211144020(Untitled_16).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-20140211144020(Untitled_17).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-20140211144020(Untitled_18).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-20140211144020(Untitled_19).csv
```

I would like this part removed: 
`20140211144020` (this is the timestamp the reports were run so this will vary)

and end up with something like:

```
CombinedReports_LLL-(Untitled_1).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-(Untitled_11).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-(Untitled_110).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-(Untitled_111).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-(Untitled_12).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-(Untitled_13).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-(Untitled_14).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-(Untitled_15).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-(Untitled_16).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-(Untitled_17).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-(Untitled_18).csv
CombinedReports_LLL-(Untitled_19).csv
```

I was thinking simply along the lines of the [mv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174947/removing-a-part-of-filename-of-a-bunch-of-files) command, maybe something like this:

```
$ ls CombinedReports_LLL-*'('*.csv
```

but maybe a [sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19166/bash-shell-script-to-locate-and-remove-substring-within-a-filename) command or other would be better

Comment: Possible duplicate of [removing a part of filename of a bunch of files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174947/removing-a-part-of-filename-of-a-bunch-of-files).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`rename` is part of the `perl` package.  It renames files according to perl-style regular expressions.  To remove the dates from your file names:

```
rename 's/[0-9]{14}//' CombinedReports_LLL-*.csv
```

If `rename` is not available, `sed`+`shell` can be used:

```
for fname in Combined*.csv ; do mv "$fname" "$(echo "$fname" | sed -r 's/[0-9]{14}//')" ; done
```

The above loops over each of your files.  For each file, it performs a `mv` command:  `mv "$fname" "$(echo "$fname" | sed -r 's/[0-9]{14}//')"` where, in this case, `sed` is able to use the same regular expression as the `rename` command above.  `s/[0-9]{14}//` tells `sed` to look for 14 digits in a row and replace them with an empty string.

Comment: No need for sed -- a modern shell can do its own substitutions built-in.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy (1) I generally aim for Dash-compatibility not just because it is so much faster than bash but also because plain shell is much more widely supported.  (2) while Bash can do primitive substitutions, sed's regex's are ultimately much more powerful.

Comment: The PEs available in POSIX sh, and thus dash, are sufficient for this particular job. Granted, you can't do replacements, but you **can** filter for beginning and ending strings and combine them. As for the claim that sed's regexes are more powerful -- bash has built-in regex support as well (see `BASH_REMATCH`), and has a mode in which its globs are comparable in power to BREs (see `extglob`).

Comment: ...the big difference, though, is efficiency; if you were iterating over hundreds of files, the time penalty of forking a subshell, exec'ing sed within it, wait()ing for that subshell to complete, read()ing its output, etc. adds up quickly.

Comment: ...also, there are side effects to using command substitution -- any time you use `$(foo)`, trailing characters in `IFS` are stripped, so a filename ending with whitespace would have that whitespace stripped, even if that's not the behavior you wanted.

Comment: `rename` might works a little bit different than described by @John1024:
`rename from to files`. And with the same examples:
`rename 20140211144020 '' CombinedReports_LLL-*'('*.csv`

Comment: @user890739 _"rename might works a little bit different than described"_  You are referring to a _different_ `rename`.  The `rename` discussed in this answer, as mentioned in the first sentence of the answer, is the version that comes with the _perl_ package.  The perl version is the default on debian-like systems.  You may be describing the version that comes as part of the `util-linux` package.

Answer (score 10):

Without using an other tools like `rename` or `sed` and sticking strictly to `bash` alone:

```
for f in CombinedReports_LLL-*.csv
do
  newName=${f/LLL-*\(/LLL-(}
  mv -i "$f" "$newName"
done
```

Comment: +1. But why not put all in mv command directly? `mv -i  "$f" "${f/LLL-*\(/LLL-(}"`

Comment: Why?  For clarity of course.  Look into the hearts and minds of the fellow programmer and guess which solution will be understood best.  My guess was, by the way OP put his question, that he would understand it better with a speaking variable name like `newName`.

Comment: Is that a standard regex? Or some bash-specific kind? I can't find any docs on a bash-specific regex language but don't understand why `LLL` is repeated or the second opening bracket.

Comment: It is not a regexp.  It is more or less a glob-pattern replacement.  See `man bash` and search for `Pattern substitution`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for f in CombinedReports_LLL-* ; do
    b=${f:0:20}${f:34:500}
    mv "$f" "$b"
done
```

You can try line by line on shell:

```
f="CombinedReports_LLL-20140211144020(Untitled_11).csv"
b=${f:0:20}${f:34:500}
echo $b
```

Comment: Let's hope all numbers (the timestamps) are of the same width.  And still, anybody reading that code will have to guess where those constants (`0`, `20`, `34`, and `500`) have come from and what they mean.  It's not impossible to guess of course, but it's not the clearest way to put it either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rename` utility for this. It uses syntax much like sed to change filenames. The following example (from the rename man-page) shows how to remove the trailing '.bak' extension from a list of backup files in the local directory:

```
rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak
```

Comment: don't have the `rename` command in my version of cygwin at the minute. any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the advice given in the top response and have put the following line into a shell script:

```
ls *.nii | xargs rename 's/[f_]{2}//' f_0*.nii
```

In terminal, this line works perfectly, but in my script it will not execute and reads * as a literal part of the file name.