# how rename a multiple files at one go in linux

Tags: linux

I have multiple files in a folder and files name format like below

**12.xyz.dat.cache**
**13.abc.dat.cache**

I have to rename above files like below

**12.xyz.dat**
**13.abc.dat**

Basically I have to remove tailing '.cache' Can you provide the command.

I tried below, did not work.

```
rename 's/\.dat\.cache$/\.dat' *.dat.cache
```

Thanks, Mahdu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing part of a filename for multiple files on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12174947/608639)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you missed the trailing slash '/' in the perlexp. And to be sure to catch a '.dat' file, you should escape the .:

```
rename 's/\.dat.cache$/\.dat/' *.dat.cache
```

Try this one.

Comment: Did not work. Tried rename 's/\.dat.cache$/\.dat/' *.dat.cache and rename 's/\.dat\.cache$/\.dat/' *.dat.cache

Comment: @Madhuprathap, the answer is working. Maybe you are missing something else. Weird whitespace chars at the start/end of the file names?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have or don't like rename, you can use this following alternative for remove all trailing .cache :

```
find . -name '*.cache' | while read NAME; do mv "${NAME}" "${NAME%.cache}"; done
```

Comment: Another suggestion following the same idea: 

==>  for file in *.cache ; do mv "${file}" "${file%.cache}" ; done

It saves a call to find...